Small decimal number in Snowflake not calculated correctly
When I calculate 1 / 100,000,000 in Snowflake like this:
SELECT (1 / 100000000)::NUMBER(38,12);

The result shows as 0:

0.000000000000

Even though the precision is sufficiently high.
When I however remove two zeroes, and divide 1 / 1,000,000 then it works as expected:
SELECT (1 / 1000000)::NUMBER(38,12);

Then I get the correct result 0.000001:

0.000001000000

What's going on here?

When performing the division operands have the following data types:
SELECT 1, 100000000,  (1 / 100000000);
DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- NUMBER(1,0) -- NUMBER(9,0) -- NUMBER(7,6)

DIVISION:

When performing division:

The leading digits for the output is the sum of the leading digits of the numerator and the scale of the denominator.

Snowflake minimizes potential overflow in the output (due to chained division) and loss of scale by adding 6 digits to the scale of the numerator, up to a maximum threshold of 12 digits, unless the scale of the numerator is larger than 12, in which case the numerator scale is used as the output scale.


If the result of the division operation exceeds the output scale, Snowflake rounds the output (rather than truncating the output).

Therefore casting should be performed before division:
SELECT (1 / 100000000)::NUMBER(38,12);
-- 0.000000000000

=> 

SELECT 1::NUMBER(38,12) / 100000000;
-- 0.000000010000

